# What is the need of redux in react?

Tags: reactjs, redux

When we have component to write all logic then why we use redux. As we can separate template and styling from component

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest words, you need redux for very complex state management in a large project. When you work on a large production level project, there are several components and states to worry about, and passing components between states becomes a mess. You could use context but in many cases you may need to move state up by 1 or more components to be able to use it effectively. This kind of problem is what redux aims to solve, and you will not be able to appreciate unless you work on a large project where components depend on other component's states.